# How to insert conditional fields with WTForms?

Tags: python, forms, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

In a website I'm building with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) I'm using [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for form validation. I currently have a field which is dependent on another field: if a user inserts a specific year (2012) a couple radio buttons are inserted using Javascript. I made the RadioField optional, which works fine, but if I actually do submit the form with the radiobuttons the value of it remains `None`.

To talk some code; the two relevant form fields are defined as follows:

```
construction_year = IntegerField('construction_year')
transfer_tax_rate = SelectField('transfer_tax_rate', validators=[Optional()], choices=[('ZERO', '0%'), ('SIX', '6%')])
```

the code I first used in the template to display the `construction_year` and `transfer_tax_rate` is as follows:

```
{{ form.construction_year(size=10) }}
{{ form.transfer_tax_rate() }}
```

This works fine; I can print out the values on the back end like so:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    print form.construction_year.data  # prints out '2012'
    print form.transfer_tax_rate.data  # prints out ZERO or SIX depending on my choice
```

I then removed `{{ form.transfer_tax_rate() }}` and wrote some Javascript which inserts the some html if the `construction_year` is 2012:

```
function displayTransferTaxRate(){
    var year = $("#construction_year").val();
    var propertyType = $("#property_type").val();
    if (year.length == 4 && year == 2012) {
        var transferTaxRateHtml = 'Applicable tax rate <select id="transfer_tax_rate" name="transfer_tax_rate"><option value="ZERO">0%</option><option value="SIX">6%</option></select>';
        $('#transfer-tax-rate-div').html(transferTaxRateHtml);
    } else {
        $('#transfer-tax-rate-div').html('');
    }
}
$("#construction_year").on('keyup paste', displayTransferTaxRate);
```

for easy reading; the html it inserts is as follows:

```
<select id="transfer_tax_rate" name="transfer_tax_rate">
    <option value="ZERO">0%</option>
    <option value="SIX">6%</option>
</select>
```

The html gets inserted fine, and I can select either of the options. But when I submit the form and try to get the value of the transfer_tax_rate as follows, it always prints out `None`:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    print form.construction_year.data  # prints out '2012'
    print form.transfer_tax_rate.data  # prints out None
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Following the tip from user3147268 below I aslo tried getting it from the standard flask `request.form`, but that doesn't contain an entry for `'transfer_tax_rate'` either.

Comment: Did you pass the form from the view to the template in which there's your javascript code?

Comment: @boh - Yes I did. All the other fields show up fine, and return fine. Everything else works perfectly well. It's just that one field that doesn't return well. I suspected that it is because I create it dynamically using js, but I have no idea if that's true, or how I can solve it.

Comment: Instead of using form.transfer_tax_rate.data you could try  request.form['transfer_tax_rate'] which is provided by Flask itself.

Comment: I've created the same form, commeted `{{ form.transfer_tax_rate() }}` out and entered the usually by flask-wtf rendered HTML manually inside the browser to simulate your JS. Everything worked fine. You should look at your JS code. Maybe you inserted the HTML not properly or you misspelled the code, that I added manually.

Comment: Did you enclose your select in a form tag? I suggest to retry with Jinja (`{{ form.transfer_tax_rate() }}`) and see if there are differences between html codes.

Comment: @user3147268 - I just found the solution! It was not related to any of the python or javascript. It turned out the placement of the form tag within a table matters a lot for dynamically added fields.. :S Checkout my answer below..

Comment: @boh - In the end I solved it, but it was a pretty weird reason (see my answer below). Thanks for your time and energy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after about 5 hours of banging my head against the wall, I'll answer my own question, because you guys could not have known this.

It turns out that it was related to a table in which this form was embedded. I left that information out, because I didn't expect that to be relevent.

So this works fine:

```
<table>
    <form action="" method="post" id="prop-form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <tr>
            <td>Construction year: </td>
            <td>
                {{ form.construction_year(size=10) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Transfer tax rate: </td>
            <td>
                {{ form.transfer_tax_rate()
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save property"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

But when I add the exact same html in this div, it doesn't work anymore:

```
<table>
    <form action="" method="post" id="prop-form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <tr>
            <td>Construction year: </td>
            <td>
                {{ form.construction_year(size=10) }}
                <div id="transfer-tax-rate-div"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save property"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

whereas, without the table around it, it does work:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="prop-form">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
Construction year: {{ form.construction_year(size=10) }} <br />
<div id="transfer-tax-rate-div"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Save property">
</form>
```

The solution turned out to lie in the placement of the `<form>` tags, because if I move them out of the table like this last piece of code, it all works fine:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="prop-form">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Construction year: </td>
        <td>
            {{ form.construction_year(size=10) }}
            <div id="transfer-tax-rate-div"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save property"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Excuse me for bothering all you guys and girls time whilst not providing all the relevant information. Thank you for giving me the energy to keep on looking though!